# Error 422 for Simple Login Activity

Tags: java, android

[Emulator output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8aCB1.png)  [Event Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NU7o3.png)  LoginActivity.java

```
package com.example2.sp.logandreg;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.Response.ErrorListener;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String TAG ="LoginActivity";
private static final String URL_FOR_LOGIN = 
"http://staging.giftintime.com/mobile/users/sign_in";
ProgressDialog progressDialog;

private EditText et_email, et_pw;
private Button btn_login;
private  Button btn_signup;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    //progress dialog
    progressDialog=new ProgressDialog(this);
    progressDialog.setCancelable(false);


    et_email=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
    et_pw = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pw);
    btn_login = (Button)findViewById(R.id.login);
    btn_signup = (Button) findViewById(R.id.signup);

    btn_login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

   loginUser(et_email.getText().toString(),et_pw.getText().toString());
        }
    });

    btn_signup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this,Signup.class));
        }
    });
}


private void loginUser(final String email,final String password) {
    String cancel_req_tag = "login";   // Tag used to cancel the request
    progressDialog.setMessage("Logging u in...");
    showDialog();
    StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, 
URL_FOR_LOGIN, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Register Response:" + response.toString());
            hideDialog();
            try {
                JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                boolean error = jObj.getBoolean("error");

                if (!error) {
                    String user = 
 jObj.getJSONObject("user").getString("name");
                    //launch second activity

                    Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, 
SecondActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("username", user);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                } else {
                    String errorMsg = jObj.getString("error_msg");
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), errorMsg, 
Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Login error:" + error.getMessage());
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            hideDialog();
        }
    }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap <String, String>();       // Posting params to login url
            params.put("email", email);
            params.put("password", password);
            return params;
        }
    };
   // Adding request to request queue
            AppSingleton.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).addToRequestQueue(strReq,cancel_req_tag);
}

private void showDialog() {
    if(!progressDialog.isShowing())
        progressDialog.show();
}
private void hideDialog() {
    if(progressDialog.isShowing())
        progressDialog.dismiss();
  }
}
```

AppSingleton.java
    package com.example2.sp.logandreg;

```
import android.content.Context;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

public class AppSingleton {

private static AppSingleton mAppSingletonInstance;
private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
private static Context mContext;

private AppSingleton(Context context){
    mContext=context;
    mRequestQueue= getRequestQueue();
}

public static synchronized AppSingleton getInstance(Context context){
    if(mAppSingletonInstance==null){
        mAppSingletonInstance = new AppSingleton(context);
    }
    return mAppSingletonInstance;
}

public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
    if(mRequestQueue==null){
        // getApplicationContext() is key, it keeps you from leaking the
        // Activity or BroadcastReceiver if someone passes one in.
        mRequestQueue= 
Volley.newRequestQueue(mContext.getApplicationContext());
    }
    return mRequestQueue;
}
public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T>req,String tag){
    req.setTag(tag);
    getRequestQueue().add(req);
  }
}
```

Gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 26
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example2.sp.logandreg"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner 
 "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
    'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-
core:3.0.1'
}
```

This code includes java file for "login activity" using API with Gradle file included. The code does not connect to the "url" mentioned. I'am new to android coding not able to sort it out. Could anyone please help me out.

Thank you.

Comment: Where have you defined ur url?

Comment: please define _not working_.

Comment: Post your logcat here

Comment: @SripadRaj: Not able to connect to the server with the mentioned URL.

Comment: @MohitHooda: Here is the URL-                                                     
 private static final String URL_FOR_LOGIN = 
"http://staging.giftintime.com/mobile/users/sign_in";

Comment: @Abhishekkumar: I have attached the screenshot, please check it out.

Comment: Have you checked this url with postman ?@sukhisukhi

Comment: @Abhishekkumar: yes, i did and the url is working fine.

Comment: @sukhisukhi , Sorry for late reply . Have you solved your issue ?

Comment: It's fine, no I haven't.. I am facing the same issue with the registration activity as well.. @Abhishek kumar

Comment: Can you check url with the backend team , are they have session management with the API , If they mentioned session management with the API then it will not work on Android.

Comment: Yeah, checked with them, they haven't used session management with the API's. I am not able to figure out if my code has issues or is it with the URL. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

You are getting error when you are making request with email id and password since its has code 422  so volley is getting a error response so you just have to handle error in error response

```
 private void loginUser(final String email,final String password) {
        String cancel_req_tag = "login";   // Tag used to cancel the request
        progressDialog.setMessage("Logging u in...");
        showDialog();
        StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, 
    URL_FOR_LOGIN, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Register Response:" + response.toString());
                hideDialog();
                try {
                    JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                    boolean error = jObj.getBoolean("error");

                    if (!error) {
                        String user = 
     jObj.getJSONObject("user").getString("name");
                        //launch second activity

                        Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, 
    SecondActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra("username", user);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();
                    } else {
                        String errorMsg = jObj.getString("error_msg");
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), errorMsg, 
    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Login error:" + error.getMessage());
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                hideDialog();
// show user error message

      try {
                        if(error.networkResponse!=null) {
                            if (error.networkResponse.data != null) {
                                String responseBody = new String(error.networkResponse.data, "utf-8");
                                JSONObject exception = new JSONObject(responseBody);
                                Toast.makeText(VerificationCodeActivity.this, exception.getString("message"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }


                    } catch ( JSONException e ) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
    //Handle a malformed json response
                    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
            }
        }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap <String, String>();       // Posting params to login url
                params.put("email", email);
                params.put("password", password);
                return params;
            }
        };
       // Adding request to request queue
                AppSingleton.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).addToRequestQueue(strReq,cancel_req_tag);
    }

    private void showDialog() {
        if(!progressDialog.isShowing())
            progressDialog.show();
    }
    private void hideDialog() {
        if(progressDialog.isShowing())
            progressDialog.dismiss();
      }
```

Comment: I added that piece of code u had sent, it doesn't work. It just displays the "Toast" message and stops. Can u suggest anything else so that the code works?

Comment: It means you are getting error from server ask your server person to solve that error